# Material UI components not working in React JS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, web-development-server

this is my app.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import {Button} from "@mui/material";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>COVID-19 TRACKER</h1>
      <Button variant="outlined">Text</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

it should display desired button but instead there is a blank screen [image]

And also there is an error in console log[image]

Kindly help me overcome this error

Comment: shared your package.json file code for which dependency is installed.?

Comment: I think you need to rewrite and the functionality between 
 export default class App extends React.Component {}. I hope it may helps

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.6"
  }
}

Comment: hi, it seems like there's no issue in this App component. are you calling any hooks in other components ? the issues seems to be you calling a hook outside the body of component. so the reason why you cant see anything is because its not rendering anything due to the issue in your hook call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe importing button like in examples might help? Try `import Button from '@mui/material/Button';`

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import {Button} from "@mui/material";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>COVID-19 TRACKER</h1>
      <Button variant="outlined">Text</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command.

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps
npm install @mui/icons-material --legacy-peer-deps
```

> Github Issue : https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32074

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the code what you are showing.

**The error comes from the Button component**, check it on line 224.

Im pretty sure what you are **calling a hook from the wrong place**, but because you did not provided the code, I can't show you exactly how to solve it.

You can do this: comment out the hook calls what you are making in the button component.

After that the site should render.

Then you can use that as a start point to make corrections.

What you need to do is simply change the place from **where** you are calling the hook/hooks.

**Make sure what they are call from inside the body of a functional component**

like this:

```js
const Button = () => {
    // >>>>>>>> here you can call hooks for example:
    const [exampleValue, setExampleValue] = useState("initial value");


    return (
        <div>
            <button>Im a button</button>
        </div>
    );
} 



// if you are using the classes syntax you have to use the constructor instead with this.state and maybe lifecycle methods.
```

Here you can learn more about it: [official docs and tutorials](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks)! - begginer friendly! ;)